# MS-Access Subform Reference Rabbit Hole

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've got a subform buried under a number of levels and am have trouble referencing it.

If we call this subform I'm trying to get to **CourseSubForm2**, it is on the second page of tab control **CourseTabControlPage2**, the tab control is on a subform **CourseSubForm1** and then that subform is on the main form **EnrolMainForm**.

Or, as a tree:

```
EnrolMainForm
 - CourseSubForm1
    - CourseTabControlPage2 (<- this is the name of the tab page, not the whole tab control)
       - CourseSubForm2
```

I'm basically trying to get the record count of what's currently on display in **CourseSubForm2** and then put that in the `.Caption` property of the second page of the control tab.

My attempt::

```vb
Public Sub EnrolCompAims()

    Dim EnrolCompAims As String

    EnrolCompAims = Trim(Forms![EnrolMainForm]![CourseSubForm1].Form![CourseSubForm2].Form.RecordsetClone.RecordCount)

    Forms![EnrolMainForm]![CourseSubForm1].Form![CourseTabControlPage2].Caption = "Component Aims (" & EnrolCompAims & ")"

End Sub
```

No error is occurring with my above attempt, but the `EnrolCompAims` is equating to 0. The record I'm testing this on has 4 records in the subform that the `RecordCount` is being applied to.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix it, but typically to get a accurate RecordCount you need to move to the last record (`.MoveLast`).

Comment: Yeah, just looking at testing that now.. thought if there are records RecordsetCount would be at least 1 though..

Comment: Yeah, same issue. It still believes the subform I'm trying to reference has 0 records; doing a `.MoveLast` on a recordset that has no records just gives me the error "No Current Record".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed.

My referencing was fine, but I was calling my `EnrolComAims()` sub routine from the current event of my main form. I guess that event occurs before records are loaded in **CourseSubForm2** subform.

I called `EnrolComAims()` from the current event of **CourseSubForm2** and now it works fine.